# Adjusting / snapping a polygon to another in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology

I have a feature class and/or Shapefile that consists of 2 complex polygons.   I would like to remove the small gaps between these polygons 1 & 2,  but I want  polygon 1 to remain exactly the same and only move polygon 2.   I've tried using topology, but I don't see how to make a rule that keeps a record the same and only moves another.

Comment: I've tried using integrate,  but both of the polygons move, even when I select one of the polygons.

Comment: I think your question would benefit from a picture of the input and desired output for a few polygons.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a one-off editing task you could select polygon 1, then *Create Layer From Selected Features*, repeat for polygon 2.  Then use the *Snap* tool under the *Editing Tools*.

Set **polygon 2 selection** as your Input Features with **polygon 1 selection** as your Snap Environment with an appropriate snapping Type and Distance.

Polygon 1 will remain unchanged and vertices in polygon 2 will be adjusted within the snapping distance.

[image]